# Problem installing R

Tags: 10.10, installation

I recently removed my Windows partition and am now running just Ubuntu 10.10

I wanted to reinstall the latest version of R, but I some weird error messages.

I'm using the instruction on their website to install:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

```
~$ deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu maverick/
No command 'deb' found, did you mean:
 Command 'debc' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'derb' from package 'libicu-dev' (main)
 Command 'dab' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
 Command 'debi' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'xdeb' from package 'xdeb' (universe)
deb: command not found
```

What's going on? Help?!

When I reinstalled Ubuntu and removed the Windows partition, the ubuntu terminal had a message at the start of the terminal. This didn't happen earlier when I was dual booting.

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you missed the

> in your /etc/apt/sources.list file

in the instructions, you add that line in a file, not on the terminal. You need to add that line to your software sources:

- [How do I add a software source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36484/how-do-i-add-a-software-source)

Comment: AH, I just reread the instruction and that's what it said. Thanks! +1

Comment: I got this error message:  GPG error: http://cran.wustl.edu maverick/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9

Answer (score 1):

You can install R easily in Ubuntu by issuing this command at the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install littler
```

It will install the GNU R frontend. (Package details [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/littler))

when prompted for your password, type in the password you use to log in to Ubuntu, or the one you provided when you were installing Ubuntu.

And to answer the second question, it's just a piece of information that tell you how to execute a command as the 'root' user. Such as when you want to install R in the above fashion. (I'm frankly not sure why it didn't appear when you were dual booting.)