# How do I add a software source?

Tags: package-management, software-sources

Sometimes I see sites offering Ubuntu packages via something like

> Add this line  to your software sources: deb http:// something something

How can I add these to my package manager so I can install the software and keep it up to date? I'd like both GUI and command line options.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can easily add them in the `Software Center`->Edit->Software Sources->Other Sources->Add"

1. Start the `Software Center`.
2. In the panel go to `Edit` and select `Software Sources`.

   [image: edit-software-sources]
3. In the tab `Other Sources` click on the `Add` button at the bottom.

   [image: other-sources]
4. Add the deb URL in the `APT Line` input field and hit `Add Source`.

   [image: software-properties-gtk]

Once you close the `Software Sources` window your cache is going to be updated automatically.

You can now browse the newly added source in the `New Source` sub-list using the upper left list in `Get Software`.

Answer (score 10):

From the command line we may add software sources by

```
sudo add-apt-repository deb http://something something
```

This will add the given source to our sources.list. We may need to additionally import a signature key:

```
sudo apt-key add <downloaded-keyfile>
```

---

There is a short form for a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<lp-user>/<ppa-name>
```

that will expand the entries for the sources list and automatically imports the gpg key.

---

After having added a new source we need to update the package index files in any case by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another version.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the deb URL to bottom of file and save it. After that you have to update the apt cache with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install software from that source just like from any other source using

```
sudo apt-get install [packagename]
```