# How to install libgdal1 1.9.1 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation

In Ubuntu 12.04 the libgdal version is 1.7.x and QLandkarte 1.4 needs libgdal1 => 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

To enable packages not in the standard repos you are going to need to use PPAs

These 2 appear to fit the bill.

https://launchpad.net/~mms-prodeia/+archive/qlandkarte

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable

Please note the description of the second -

> These releases are more bleeding edge and while generally they should
>   work well, they dont receive the same amount of quality assurance as
>   our stable releases do.

In fact - with any PPA you need to be aware that it is not official, this answer has more detail - https://askubuntu.com/a/35636/2018

To install from a terminal

```
Ctrl+Shift+T
```

Then run these one at a time - follow the instructions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mms-prodeia/qlandkarte
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

You should then be able to install (or update) qlandkarte

You can also add them into software sources from a GUI

https://askubuntu.com/a/36487/2018

Comment: +1 for details and effort. Surprised I'm the first to vote. It's a shame that askubuntu seems to not have the same sense of appreciation that other SE sites do.