# Software Properties KDE is not opening after installation!

Tags: 12.04, kde, software-sources

though I install Software Properties KDE its not opening and showing an message, *Please run this software with administrative rights. To do so, run this program with kdesudo.* Even though I am the admin.[image: this is the screenshort of the error message.]

Comment: Admin is distinct from sudo. How are you opening this application? And also, why are you using KDE program in Unity?

Comment: how admin is distinct from sudo? how can i solve it?

Comment: Administrators have access to the sudo/kdesudo/gksudo commands. I might be able to help you solve it if you answer my questions in the first comment. :)

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand your first question. :(

Comment: Okay, no worries. I meant to ask two questions: (1) what method do you use to launch this program? So you click on a shortcut in the left-bar launcher, or use the command line, etc.? (2) This is a KDE program, written with the KDE desktop environment in mind. From the screenshot, you are using the (default) Unity desktop environment. So why are you using this program?

Comment: actually I am a new user of Ubuntu. There is no specific reason to use this software:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`software-properties-kde` is a program bundled with the KDE desktop environment for configuring what repositories are used for software sources. It requires superuser privileges, hence you are getting the error message to run it with `kdesudo software-properties-kde` (although I agree the error message is slightly misleading).

However, since you are using the Unity desktop environment, then I'd suggest sticking with the bundled application for configuring software sources that comes with Unity. I would suggest doing this via the GUI. i.e. `Software Center` > Edit > Software Sources…, similar to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/36487/53508).

(Side note: if you run `software-properties-kde` from the GUI in KDE, i.e. from Muon Software Centre, it will automatically attempt to run with kdesudo.)