# Installing programs from Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, software-center

On Ubuntu 14, I used to always use Ubuntu Software Center to find and install programs, plugins etc. You could easily find anything by typing the name in the search bar. But now in Ubuntu 16.04 things don't work like that anymore for some reason... It doesn't find any programs other than I already have installed (not even GIMP or Adobe Flash Player...).

And when I try to install program from website by opening it by default in Ubuntu Software it gives me the message: "failed to open". Can anyone help me out here? How can I install programs on Ubuntu 16?

Comment: It depend on repositories you add for this reason most user prefer install using terminal

Comment: for more information https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu
or 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/36484/how-do-i-add-a-software-source

Answer (score 1):

Canonical decided to pull the plug on the Ubuntu Software Center in version 16.04. The Ubuntu Software Center has now been replaced by the Gnome Software Center. You can still install software there just like when Ubuntu still had USC.

I hope you find what you are looking for. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

---

The two classic 'Package Managers' can still be installed :

`sudo apt-get install software-center synaptic`

---

---